# MySQL union + limit

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my query

```
select PhoneNumber as _data,PhoneType as _type from contact_phonenumbers where ContactID = 3 and Type = 'R' and PT = 'M' 
union 
SELECT EmailID,Type  from contact_emails where ContactID = 3 and Type = 'P' 
UNION
SELECT EmailID,Type from contact_emails where ContactID = 3 and Type = 'O'
```

Here my problem is i need to fetch only one row from each select statement. Is it possible to fetch it through "limit".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to MySQL website you can apply limit to an individual select like that

```
(SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10);
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html